# SQL how to find out the column that correlates most with one specific column

Tags: sql, presto, trino

Hi I have a data set that looks like:

```
A1  A2  ... A100  Target 
7   7   ... 2     2
2   2   ... 3     4
2   2   ... 2     4
2   2   ... 2     3
5   5   ... 2     7
```

I would like to find out which column among A{1, 2, ... 100} mostly correlates with Target column. If number of columns is small, I know I can simply do `CORR` for each of them, but in this case, what is the best practice? Thanks

Comment: That is the best practice.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is there something like a for loop for SQL here? or probably I should get the data offline for analysis in python

Comment: Really, the best practice is to not use SQL as a general purpose statistics tool.  But you don't have much choice if you are doing this in SQL.